# Open each spreadsheet in a new instance of Excel in Windows 7

Tags: excel-2010

How do I configure Excel to open a new instance of Excel each time I open an existing spreadsheet. I am using Office 2010 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this, go to 'excel options' > click on the 'advanced' tab > scroll down to general > check the ignore other applications that use 'Dyanamic Data Exchange (DDE)'

Answer (score 4):

Freddy, in some cases this does not work. It comes up with error dialog box and sheets cannot be opened. Suppose it might depend on LAN configuration among other things.

Elsewhere on web there are instructions about changing registry but if you on a locked down LAN you have to resort to opening separate Excel from desktop or start menu then file-open different file in each open instance of Excel.

Comment: Any examples of "elsewhere on web"?

Answer (score 0):

File > Options > Advanced > General > [CHECK] Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) > OK

Opening new Excel files will now open a new instance each time.